# What are some alternatives of AsyncMock in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, pytest

I have been using AsyncMock for some of the test cases. AsyncMock is introduced only in Python 3.8 but I am using 3.7.

I am looking for some alternatives.

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch(
    "project.celerytasks.embedder.BulkEmbedder.fetch_embedding",
    mock.AsyncMock(return_value=embedding_response),
)
def test_document_embedding():

    doc = {
        "orgId": "orgtest"
    }

    doc = embed(document=doc, embedding_endpoint=embedding_endpoint)

    assert doc["subdocuments"]

    assert len(doc["title_embedding"]) == embedding_dim
    assert len(doc["subdocuments"]) == len(doc["paragraphs"])

    assert len(doc["subdocuments"][0][embedding_name]) == embedding_dim
```

Error:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting code/tests/test_embedder.py ____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

tests/test_embedder.py:18: in <module>

    mock.AsyncMock(return_value=embedding_response),

E   AttributeError: module 'unittest.mock' has no attribute 'AsyncMock'

============================================================================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================================================================

ERROR tests/test_embedder.py - AttributeError: module 'unittest.mock' has no attribute 'AsyncMock'

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

================================================================================================================================== 1 error in 6.02s ==================================================================================================================================
```